# c# Mvc HttpContext.Current.Items and Clearing when request is complete diff

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web

Lets say that you are storing a Entity Framework DBConect in the HttpContext.Current.Items

When the request is finished... does it make a difference if you do?

```
protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest() {
    var entityContext = HttpContext.Current.Items["myContext"] as DbEnitities
    if (entityContext != null)
    entityContext.Dispose();
}
```

Or not... since the HttpContext.Current.Items only lives for the request and will no longer exist after the request is complete... it should clear all its contents anyway.

or will the connection technically still be open and only closed when the GC(garbage collection) is called? so basically all it would do is close the connection sooner? what is the negative of this.... I assume an open connection really doesn't consume that much memory.

Is it more correct to have the Application_BeginRequest and close the connection or not?
Since this should all happen automatically anyway... are there any benefits or negatives to doing this?

Would prefer a long technically explanation with supporting info, rather than "Yes" as an answer.

Comment: [here](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)'s a nice post that may help you.

Comment: that was great! and will mark as the answer...if i don't get anything better over a period of time. The link leads into what I'm asking in my question...assuming that you do not manually open a connection. Is there any benefit to clearing out HttpContext.Current.Items as technically it should clear itself out? as its life span is only the length of the request.

Comment: so adding any code to Application_BeginRequest(), to clear HttpContext.Current.Items pointless? in other words is, it better with it or without it.

Comment: I'd say that adding EF context to `HttpContext.Current` is a **very very** bead design choice. It's better to go with injection of repository/service/ef context into controller. though EF is clever enough to close connection it's recommended to dispose it by yourself (actually everything that is `IDisposable`) just in case.

Comment: also, object that created `IDisposable` has to control it's lifetime (from creation to disposing). in your case creation and disposing is performed in different places by different objects which is not a...good practice. when you are injecting `IDisposable` using any IoC container it will (if correctly configured) create desired object and dispose when time comes. this is much better approach. IMO of course.

Comment: I get you... agreed I am not designing it this way... was existing code and was just interested as to whether the code in the Application_BeginRequest was actually needed...making a diff, I prefer a KISS IoC design. But your input is valuable... and i agree.